# Registering derived classes in central list

Tags: c++

I have a central list of implementations of an interface and would like for derived classes to be able to register themselves in that list without having to add them in some central place. For example:

```
// interface.h
struct MyInterface;
std::vector<MyInterface*>& InterfaceList();

struct MyInterface {
    MyInterface() {
       InterfaceList().push_back(this);
    }
    virtual ~MyInterface() {}
    // ...
};

// derived.cpp
#include "interface.h"
class MyImplementation: public MyInterface {
public:
    MyImplementation() {
    }
    // ...
};

MyImplementation impl;
```

This doesn't seem to work. For reasons I don't understand, the constructor of MyInterface never gets called - I would have thought that the instance of the derived class would call it at startup. I know it's possible to do something along these lines since I've seen other libraries doing it - but haven't managed to figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Thanks :)

Edit: Sorry, missed a pair of braces and a reference. InterfaceList() is a function that returns a reference to a vector.

Edit part 2: Have now got it working in a reduced example, but can't get it to work in the files for the derived implementations - but that technique is working in another project. There must be something slightly different in those files which is causing it to fail - but it appears the problem isn't in the code I posted. Don't really want to post big chunks of my employer's projects though so I guess I'll have to keep fiddling myself. Thanks for the suggestions so far though :)

Comment: where is your virtual dtor? you need one in your base class.

Comment: Anders: I'm trying to post a simplified version of the code, so have left out a few bits and pieces. For the purposes of this discussion, I don't care if it leaks memory :)

Answer (score 2):

You example does not compile under VS2008. What compiler are you using? When you change the second line in `interface.h` to

```
std::vector<MyInterface*> InterfaceList;
```

it works correctly. Just drop the braces.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently, and found that the simplest solution was to create a templated base class that was responsible for registering all of my implementations.

The base class contains a static variable, of templated type T, and this is registered with the central list. At runtime, each implementation would create its own static object and in the process of creating itself would register with the central list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class ITestInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void Execute() = 0;
};

std::vector<ITestInterface *> InterfaceList; 

template <class T> class BaseClass :
    public ITestInterface
{
    public:
        virtual void Execute() = 0;

    protected: 
        BaseClass()
        {
            InterfaceList.push_back(&s_thing);
        }

    private:
         static T s_thing;
};

template <class T> T BaseClass<T>::s_thing;

class ImplementationOne :
    public BaseClass<ImplementationOne>
{
    public :
        ImplementationOne():
            BaseClass()
        {
            ;
        }

        void Execute()
        {
            std::cout << "ImplementationOne Execute\r\n";
        }
};

class ImplementationTwo :
    public BaseClass<ImplementationTwo>
{
    public :
        ImplementationTwo():
            BaseClass()
        {
            ;
        }

        void Execute()
        {
            std::cout << "ImplementationTwo Execute\r\n";
        }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<ITestInterface *>::iterator it = InterfaceList.begin();
    for(; it != InterfaceList.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->Execute();
    }
}
```

The thing to remember with this code is that the line

```
static T s_thing;
```

does not result in a single s_thing, rather because a template is a type-generator there is one static s_thing for each derived class.

The output is

> ImplementationOne Execute
>
> ImplementationTwo Execute

This code works in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue:

```
std::vector<MyInterface*> InterfaceList();
```

should be

```
std::vector<MyInterface*> InterfaceList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following definition of InterfaceList is a kind of function declaration which returns  std::vector

```
std::vector<MyInterface*> InterfaceList();
```

Change this to

```
  std::vector<MyInterface*> InterfaceList;
```